# Call JInternalframe from JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I would like to call a JInternalframe from a Panel.

I got a jframeJFrame with the main method and a JDesktopPane

I have a JInternalFrame NewJInternalFrame where I call a JPanel NewJPanel

Now I would like to call another JInternalFrame NewJInternalFrame1 from my JPanel NewJPanel and add it to my JDeskptopPane dp

```
public class JFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form JFrame
     */
    public JFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {     

    private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        NewJInternalFrame s = new NewJInternalFrame();
        s.setVisible(true);
        this.jDesktopPane1.add(s);
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration                    
    private javax.swing.JDesktopPane jDesktopPane1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

public class NewJInternalFrame extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

```
public NewJInternalFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        NewJPanel up = new NewJPanel();
        jTabbedPane1.add(up);

    }                                        

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}

public class NewJInternalFrame1 extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {


    public NewJInternalFrame1() {
        initComponents();
    }



 public class NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

        /**
         * Creates new form NewJPanel
         */
        public NewJPanel() {
            initComponents();
        }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            //call NewJInteralFrame1

            NewJInternalFrame1 f1 = new NewJInternalFrame1();
                JDesktopPane desktopPane = this.getDesktopPane();
                desktopPane.add(f1);
                f1.setVisible(true);
        }                                        

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

I tried the following:

```
public class Jp1 extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            Jf2 f = new Jf2();
            JDesktopPane desktopPane = this.getDesktopPane();
            desktopPane.add(f);
            me.setVisible(true);

        }
```

But that doesn't work because it says I should create the method `getDesktopPane()`

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: um.... perhaps create the method `getDesktopPane()`? one that returns a reference to the JDesktopPane, maybe

Comment: But seriously, this question involves connections in your code, connections that we can't see or help with. If you need serious help, ask a serious question including posting valid [sscce](http://sscce.org) code.

Comment: getDesktopPane is a method of the object DesktopPane

Comment: Again, if you truly need help, put more into this question including the SSCCE (see the link) or MCVE.

Comment: I edited my post and tried to explain my issue. Excuse my poor english

Comment: Please read or re-read the [sscce](http://sscce.org) link or [mcve] link as they will explain just what code we will need to understand your problem and help you.

Comment: I tried again and added code

Comment: Don't extend `JFrame`, `JPanel` or `JInternalFrame`. Doing so complicates things and contributes to the current problems. Please read the links provided by @HovercraftFullOfEels. If you read them, it seems you did not understand the content, so ask questions where unsure.